# Editing a current process definition in Activiti

Tags: activiti

Whenever I need to make a change in the process definition I have to re deploy the process definition.It seems that creates a new version of the process definition.

Is there a way where I can update the existing process definition and not create a new version all the time.

What will happen to the old process instances if there is a new version of process definition in place.

Any help on the above queries is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the Activiti API provides a way to replace an existing process definition without deploying a new version.

When you deploy a new version of a process, any existing process instances on the old version continue running on the old version.

However, there is a [`SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd`](https://github.com/yin-bp/activiti-engine-5.12/blob/master/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/cmd/SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd.java) class you can use to change the process version on a process instance.  It's not "smart", though; it simply changes the version number, and doesn't change any other runtime data, so it can break process instances if you make an incompatible change in the process definition.

Answer (score 0):

As matts said, you can use `org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd`.

Following code is to update latest process definition id.

```
String PROCESS_DEFINITION_NAME = processdefID; 
DesEncrypter de = new DesEncrypter();
String password = "yourpwd";

ProcessEngineConfiguration cfg = new StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
 .setJdbcUrl("database.url")
 .setJdbcUsername("database.username").setJdbcPassword("database.password")
 .setJdbcDriver("database.driver")
 .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_FALSE);

ProcessEngine processEngine = cfg.buildProcessEngine();
RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();

ProcessDefinition processDefinition = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().latestVersion()
 .processDefinitionKey(PROCESS_DEFINITION_NAME).singleResult();

if (processDefinition == null) {
 System.out.println("Cannot find Process Def ID " + PROCESS_DEFINITION_NAME);
} else {
 System.out.println("Latest Process Definition Version: " + processDefinition.getVersion());
 long counter = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().active()
  .processDefinitionKey(PROCESS_DEFINITION_NAME).count();
 List < ProcessInstance > processInstanceList = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().active()
  .processDefinitionKey(PROCESS_DEFINITION_NAME).list();

 System.out.println(counter);

 System.out.println("Total process instances: " + counter);
 System.out.println("Total process instances retrieved: " + processInstanceList.size());

 int index = 1;
 for (ProcessInstance oneInstance: processInstanceList) {
  try {
   CommandConfig commandConfig = new CommandConfig();
   // Execute the command asynchronously to prevent that
   // one error updating a process instance stops the
   // entire batch
   cfg.getAsyncExecutor().getProcessEngineConfiguration().getCommandExecutor()
    .execute(commandConfig.transactionNotSupported(), new SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd(
     oneInstance.getId(), processDefinition.getVersion()));
   System.out.println(index++ + " - Process instance UPDATED: " + oneInstance.getId() +
    ", previous definition ID: " + oneInstance.getProcessDefinitionVersion());

  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(index++ + " - Process instance FAILED: " + oneInstance.getId() +
    ", previous definition ID: " + oneInstance.getProcessDefinitionVersion() +
    ",  Cause: " + e.getMessage());
  }
 }

 System.out.println("********* Completed Successfully. *********");
 System.in.read();

}
```