# Making older user tasks follow a new version of process definition

Tags: activiti

I am facing an issue.

I have huge number of user tasks in the system which were created as per an older version of process definition. I have recently deployed a new version of process definition. I want to somehow make those tasks adhere to newer version of process definition.

I understand that I may need to modify several tables.

Is there another better alternative for it?

And if not, then which all exact tables would I need to modify?

Comment: Check out this similar question from a couple of years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205814/migrating-activiti-tasks-from-old-process-to-new-process

Comment: I won't recommend this. but if don't find any other way look at this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101496/editing-a-current-process-definition-in-activiti